# MS Graph API - Create Contact 401 Issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've created an application in the Azure portal and granted it the necessary permissions. I can successfully send emails via the API and create calendar events... so I know the application is working and that the auth token is OK. However, when I try and create a new contact, I get a (401) Unauthorized error. The application does have the "Contacts.ReadWrite" permission assigned and has the admin consent granted. Has anybody else had any issues with creating contacts through the Graph API?

Their documentation seems straight forward enough and like I say, I can create events and send mail via the API without issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Could you please share the requestid, timestamp and the whole error message for the failed request. Also you can give a try with [Graph explorer](https://aka.ms/ge).

Comment: So I've just logged the response and what I get back is:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-12-02T12:58:21",
      "request-id": "fe3417d1-d4ed-4a27-b960-7e7e1082c5e6",
      "client-request-id": "fe3417d1-d4ed-4a27-b960-7e7e1082c5e6"
    }
  }

Comment: This means that you are not properly getting the token properly. Please check the token and then give a try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help. But if this is the case, why would the same token be deemed OK for creating calendar events and sending mail, but considered incorrect (not gotten properly) when used for creating a contact?

Comment: I see many times this issue happens when you don't copy the whole token string, please check that when you use create contact may be using fiddler if you are sending the token correctly.

Comment: You can also check your access token if you have permissions or not in https://jwt.ms

Comment: Did it helped you? Also check this [thread](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-dev-docs/issues/508)

Comment: @Chris, In my scenario, the problem was in syntax when calling the service..it requires "space" between "Bearer" and the token you're using. You can do it like "Bearer " + token - test and see if it helps.